# How to get the top 3 most common numbers in a column in an SQLITE3 database using Laravel?

Tags: sql, laravel, sqlite, eloquent

I am making a web app where people vote on costumers. After participants vote the number will appear in the 'votedFor' table for each particular participant. I am wondering if there is a way to get the top 3 most common numbers (the costumes with the most votes) from the 'votedFor' column and then insert them into another table. In the following example number 33, 22, and 11 would be stored but the rest would be cleared out...

```
user | votedFor
1    |  33
2    |  33
3    |  33
4    |  33
5    |  22
6    |  22
7    |  22
8    |  11
9    |  11
10   |  1
11   |  2
12   |  3
```

I do not have much code to show - I am looking around to try and figure it out. Do I need to do a raw SQL query and I should just focus on that or is there a way to do with Eloquent and SQLITE3?

Answer (score 1):

In SQLite, you can use aggregation with `order by` and `limit`:

```
select votedFor
from t
group by votedFor
order by count(*) desc
limit 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use aggregation and RANK() window function to get also ties:

```
select votedFor
from (
  select votedFor, 
         rank() over (order by count(*) desc) rnk
  from tablename
  group by votedFor
)
where rnk <= 3
order by rnk;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=44205acf238e45b2c0a6c0c5c22c498b).
Results:

```
> | votedFor |
> | -------: |
> |       33 |
> |       22 |
> |       11 |
```